# Implicit conversion from big endian byte data to ILNumerics float array?

Tags: .net, endianness, ilnumerics

I have got a huge byte array of big endian floats which I want to convert to ilnumerics float array.

Right now, I do the conversion explicitly. I generate system array of floats by reversing 4 bytes at a time and converting to float which can then be assigned to ilnumerics array.

I am looking for more efficient way to do this. Are there any flags in ILNumerics that enable implicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, endianess is not related to .NET or ILNumerics but purely a hardware thing. If you find yourself on a system which needs to read in data stored on a system with different endianess you need to convert the data manually - one by one. There is no function in ILNumerics currently which is able to support you by doing so.

You may try to utilize the automatic conversion which is built in into HDF5 (but this would be a different thread).